# How to avoid getting negative points from Google AdSense

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense, canonical-url, google-ranking

I have a news based website in which the primary contents includes news, image albums and videos. Out of these I have copyrights for the images and the videos are embedded from YouTube. My site is kinda like a mashup site, it gathers data from various other sites and presents them in a more user friendly way and for quick digestion and access. The problem I have is since the news part of the site can be found from other sites, my site could suffer in search rankings.

Is there any solution to this. One thing I thought of is to put disallow on all the news articles pages, so Google does not crawl them. Will this be helpful to me? When applying to Google AdSense does Google crawl these pages (disallow) also?

Comment: Adsense does not bother about these. It is not clear if you're asking about SEO or Adsense.

Comment: new duplication happens in all news sites and is unavoidable many times. Your site too should be treated the same way by Google if it is popular one.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to prevent Google seeing your site in a negative light is not to duplicate content from other sites. If you are simply a news aggregator, perhaps you should consider linking to the external articles as opposed to replicating them on your website. Direct duplication of content is almost certainly frowned upon.

Duplicate content will not affect your Google AdSense.

Answer (score 2):

You will get penalized by Google one way or another. AdSense will sometime ban you account after a manual or algorithmic penalty. Adding disallow on the articles pages will solve nothing, you will have nothing on your site to show to Google.

You must at least add some unique text for every news, to have partial duplicate. Even then, you will probably get bashed!

If you really bring something to the readers, check `inbound.org`, this a good aggregator.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are SCRAPPING your text content, this is against Googles Adwords Polices. (Text is also copywritted just as multimedia formats such as videos, lyrics, music etc)

Google manually reviews it ad-word accounts holders, you even need to apply for the acount first and then they are put on probation.

Similar to Google Rankings they work on trust rankings which means the less trust you have the more likely your be subject to a manual review and that's if they don't catch you from their automated bots which in all honesty they will, just take a look at good at Google's Panda was at catching sites with Thin and Duplicate content, they can easily use this technology on all of their systems for alerts.

**ADVICE**

As harsh as this may sound - stop with the duplicate content. The money you are willing to invest in buying traffic can be used on content writers that will put you back in Good status with Google, Gain Network Traffic, Earn Money from Visitors easier, and most all of your long term online survivability will be greater.

PS. You can get someone to write a 500 worded Document from $5-10 each, a adword lick could cost you $1-5 depending on the keywords, I know where I would want to invest my money.

People on Fiverr normally charge around $5 for each 500 words, ensure that they are not SPINNING content and some are better at grammar than others. You could always use your documents with a Proof Reader and have them correct the grammar issues, again these are cheap and normally $5-10 per 1000-2000 words.

**Conclusion**

Think long term and actually make a site that will gain natural visitors without the need of buying traffic.. Buying traffic should be used to boost the amount of visitors, not give you visitors.